# React text field's default value doesn't get overriden

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I'm creating a react form which has 2 input fields with a condition that is only triggered when the local state has a particular value. I've set a default value as well which is used to populate some values based on button click. But if I already type in some text and then click the button, the values don't over ride the existing. Here's the code-

```
<input type="text" name="name" ref={register} defaultValue={state.isEdit? data[idx].name:undefined}/>
```

So normally textfield is blank and when I click on a table that has some student details, the corresponding value is displayed on field.[Working], but now if suppose I have already typed in something, and then click on edit button from table, the student details don't reflect on text field.

P.S. - I'm not looking for placeholder. Also this form uses react-hook-form

Comment: Why dont you use `value` instead of `defaultValue`

Comment: Tried that @Neel Dsouza, but then field is not editable

Comment: I think this should work with value. Can you share the code you tried with value and how are you setting the value onClick? and also I think you should use "" instead of undefined there.

Comment: Sure, using "" also results in same thing.

Comment: Can u share few more code in your question?